# Powershell ConvertTo-Csv mangles objects

Tags: powershell, csv

Say I do

```
$d = @{"foo"="bar"; "baz"=99.9}
ConvertTo-csv $d
```

I'd expect something like

```
foo,baz
"bar",99.9
```

but instead I get this:

```
#TYPE System.Collections.Hashtable
"IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Keys","Values","SyncRoot","Count"
"False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","2"
```

It seems to put the metadata about the object into the CSV, not the actual content of the object.

How do I get my expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$d` is a hash table with key(name)/value pairs,
to convert first make it an object with `[PSCustomObject]`

```
PS> $d

Name                           Value
----                           -----
baz                            99,9
foo                            bar
```

---

```
PS> [PSCustomObject]$d

 baz foo
 --- ---
99,9 bar
```

Then `ConvertTo-Csv` using the paraameter `-NoTypeInformation`

```
PS> [PSCustomObject]$d|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"baz","foo"
"99,9","bar"
```

To keep your initial order use an ordered hash table

```
PS> $d = [ordered]@{"foo"="bar"; "baz"=99.9}

PS> [PSCustomObject]$d|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"foo","baz"
"bar","99,9"
```

Comment: So hash tables aren't objects? I guess I've spent too much time working with javascript. I should probably go read a manual or something.

Comment: Well a different type of an object, append `$d.GetType()` or pipe to `$d|Get-Member` to examine.